# Get developer belonging to a model

Tags: python, django

I am doing a query where I filter the developers that belong to the Project model, because I am going to make the activity model generate a list of only the developers that belong to the Project model

This is project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(Developer)
    state = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This is task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(Developer)
    type_task = models.ForeignKey(TypeTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    activities = models.ManyToManyField(Activities, through='ActivitiesTasks')
    description = models.TextField()
    state = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Example

Task.objects.filter(developer=?).exists()

Comment: Reframe your guestion title to something that can help others, project is not a name everyone will be using if they wat to accomplish the same thing, probably why you are being down voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many to many field does not work that way,
Lets say you want developers who belong to task id 1
Then

```
task =Task.objects.get(id=1)
devs = task.developer.all()
```

For the project developers you do the same, get the project you need then get all the developers in the project the same way I did with the task.

```
proj = Project.objects.get (id=1)
Devs = proj.developer.all ()
```

Comment: but I am trying to bring all the developers that belong to the Project model, in the way you suggest, only bring one

Comment: Then it means you only have one developer who is doing the project...

Comment: there are many developers and the activities can also be in many developers

Comment: Then the question you posted is not what you need. If you need all the developers than you dont have to get them by project or task `devs = Developer.objects.all()` returns all developers in your database